# Chrome installation error 106

Tags: windows-xp, google-chrome, installation

I am trying to install Chrome on small EEE Asus laptop with Windows XP (version 2002 SP 3). I download the installer ChromeSetup.exe, run it, it downloads the rest and runs the installation, but then it says something like

> Chrome installation error 106

(not literaly, I am translating the Czech message to English)

How can I fix this problem? I was googling the solution but I only found some advices on how to first properly uninstall Chrome (but I have no Chrome installation on this computer).

Comment: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/K0WuXko4n7Y